# Is there any api or method to convert instagram shortcode (shortlink) to post id?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm looking for a method to get Instagram short code to post id
for example this is short code : https://www.instagram.com/p/CauQh98LKAk/ and this is post id 18227641462099074